# Is there a reason not to map all integer types to a BigInteger in Grails Domain Classes?

Tags: grails

All of the databases seem to have recommendations on what Java object to map the various integer data types to. In DB2 for instance it is [SMALLINT: java.lang.Short, INTEGER: java.lang.Integer, BIGINT: java.lang.Long].

Is there a problem with just using java.math.BigInteger for all of them in Grails Domain classes? It would make typing them a lot simpler and resembles the decimal approach where everything is a java.math.BigDecimal.

To clarify, I do not have control of the data type in the database and would not advocate corrupting the data model by using only one integer type if I did. I am simply proposing to map all integer data types to java.math.BigInteger in the Grails Domain class, like:

```
class NdIntegerTest {
    BigInteger id
    BigInteger ndSmallint
    BigInteger ndInteger
    BigInteger ndBigint
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sum total input (thanks Joshua) I have concluded that standardizing on java.math.BigInteger is a reasonable treatment of integer data types in a Grails Domain class.

My tests were based on a class like that in the post, involving SMALLINT, INTEGER, and BIGINT data types using DB2. I tried inserting and updating rows and all seemed to go well. Where I put more data in the element than the database could accept I got the following exception (sort of).

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not...
    at ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not...
    at ...
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.bn: [jcc][10177][11599][3.51.90] Invalid data conversion: Requested conversion would result in a loss of precision of [value]. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at ...
```

The same error occurs when reading an oversized value into an undersized Domain Class variable, FWIW, which is obviously not a concern when the variable is a BigInteger.

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason, and it's storage of the data in your database. If you have a use case where you are storing the age of a person, for instance, it makes no sense to use a `BIGINT`. In some database engines, storing a `BIGINT` takes up more space than a `SMALLINT`. Obviously this makes an impact when you have billions of records but hardly matters when you have several thousand.

That's the reason.

A word of advice, **don't** use data types that aren't realistic for the type of data you expect to store. In the long run you will find your efforts to make things homogeneous just create issues in the long term. Use the right tool for the right job, and the right data type for the right bit of data.

Comment: Sorry. I must have been unclear. I was not asking how to store the data in the database, but whether mapping all integer types to a BigInteger in the Grails Domain class introduces a problem. I agree that one should not corrupt the data model (although frankly the vendor database I am dealing with is pretty corrupt already).

Comment: No it doesn't introduce any problems as Grails domains are fully capable of using those data types.

Comment: Much obliged. My tests did not turn up any difficulties but I wanted to check for any experiences to the contrary.